# Filter JSON by range dates JS

Tags: javascript, json, date, filtering

I want to filter a simple JSON file by date range.
With a start date and and end date.

And this is my function:

```
var startDate = new Date("2013-3-25");
var endDate = new Date("2017-3-25");
var aDate = new Date();

var filteredData = this.orders.filter(function(a){
aDate = new Date(a.fecha);
    aDate >= startDate && aDate <= endDate;
});
console.log(filteredData)
```

Here's my: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhhysaok/)

I'm expecting to get one object in my array, however the array is empty as you can see in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `filter` method on an array, that function needs to return a boolean to indicate to the script whether to keep a value or remove it.

You didn't return the value from within the filter function. This works:

```
var filteredData = this.orders.filter(function(a){
    aDate = new Date(a.fecha);
    return aDate >= startDate && aDate <= endDate;
});
```

Comment: Can't belive I've missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxxxx don't forget to "accept" answers! :)

Answer (score 3):

> however the array is empty as you can ses in the console.

Because `filter`'s callback method is **not returning anything**, make it

```
var filteredData = this.orders.filter(function(a){
    var aDate = new Date(a.fecha);
    return aDate.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() && aDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime();
});
```

**Note**

- Date comparison is done differently, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript).
- You need not do `getTime()` on `startDate` and `endDate` for every iteration, do it once before the `filter`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time! you're right about the return. However, the comparision dates will come in dinamically, this was just a fast fidd that i've made.

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxxxx Sure, I added the details just to complete the answer. Hopefully this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything in your filter.

```
var filteredData = this.orders.filter(function(a){
    aDate = new Date(a.fecha);
    return aDate >= startDate && aDate <= endDate;
});
```

For reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter